# Best approach to display viewport size dependent markup

Tags: html, responsive-design

CSS is not an option, the element must be completely removed an readded from the DOM. PHP mobile detect is not an option, the element must be toggled viewport size dependent.

So far this is what I found:

- Ajax & PHP
- 51Degrees PHP (https://sourceforge.net/projects/fiftyone/)
- Response JS (http://responsejs.com/)
- jQuery media comments (https://github.com/Podders/Jquery-Media-Comments/)

What is the best approach?